# Avoiding catch generic exception and use generic interface

Tags: java, oop, generics, exception

I have a requirement, where I have a generic interface to convert one entity to another as

```
public interface Converter<T,U>{
    public U convert(T src) throws Exception;
}
```

And implementation class as

```
class StringToIntConverterImpl implements Converter<String,Integer>{
    public Integer convert(Integer i) throws StringConversionException;
}
```

Now In my code I use

```
public class AppClass{
    private Converter<String,Integer> converter;
    public static void mainAppLogic(){
        try{
            converter.convert(input);
        }
        catch(Exception e){
        }
    }
}
```

Here I am having to catch generic Exception, how to avoid this ? At the same time I want to use Converter converter decalartion in my mainapp instead of specific ConverterClass since I want to program to interface so that I can switch any implementation of converter later on.

Comment: You can create an interface or base class called `ConversionException` and let all Convertors throw any implementation or sub-class of it. This way you can catch `ConversionException` instead of `Exception`

Comment: Or you can use runtime exceptions, as basically all modern classes do now, especially when it's a functional interface you want to use as a lambda. BTW, your interface already exists: [Function](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/function/Function.html).

Comment: Does the implementation of the interface in the second code block have a compile time error? Should not it be `public Integer convert(String si) throws StringConversionException;`

Comment: @SukhpalSingh are you suggesting StringConversionException extends ConversionException  ? and ConversionException  extends Exception.

Comment: @user1846749 Yes.

Answer (score 0):

You can use generic exception:

```
public interface Converter<T, U, E extends Throwable> {
    U convert(T t) throws E;
}
```

Now in your main method you can have:

```
public class AppClass{
    private Converter<String,Integer,RuntimeException> converter;
    public static void mainAppLogic(){
        converter.convert(input);
    }
}
```